# Sharepoint search not respecting noindex

Tags: 2010, search

I've got an SharePoint Site (Web), with an custom default page. On that page there's an div with styling

```
<div class="ProjectInfo noindex">             
         <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="Top" Title="loc:Top" PartChromeType="TitleOnly">
                    <ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
         </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
```

Afther doing a full crawl my index is updated. If i do an search i've got two results.
The first one is de default page. This one has excluded the content from de div.

The other result is my STS_Web site. This one is included the div. This is strange because it's the same page that was indexed.

It's not a nested div.

How can i solve this problem?